# Almacenar valores de una Tabla html a Base de Datos con Ajax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, array, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema que no logro entender, porque no se almacena los valores a la base de datos.

Tengo un JS donde almaceno los valores de una tabla a un array, para luego mandarlo al controlador a través de ajax para asi poder almacenar dichos valores en la base de datos, pero por alguna razón no me esta almacenando nada.

Ya hice un console log al array y ahí si me esta almacenando los valores, pero a la hora de mandarlos, tal vez no me los esta pasando al controlador.

JavaScript

```
function Guardar() {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var pedidos = new Array();
        $("#tPedidos TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var pedido = {};
            pedido.Producto = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();

            pre = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            pedido.Precio = pre.split('Q')[1];

            pedido.CantidadPedido = row.find("TD").eq(2).find('input').val();
            pedido.Estado = "Pendiente";
            pedidos.push(pedido);
        });           

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Pedido/InsertPedidos",
            data: JSON.stringify(pedidos),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        }
        );
        console.log(pedidos);
    };
```

Controlador

```
public JsonResult InsertPedidos(List<Pedido> pedido)
        {       
            //Check for NULL.
            if (pedido == null)
            {
                pedido = new List<Pedido>();
            }

            //Loop and insert records.
            foreach (Pedido pedidoo in pedido)
            {
                db.Pedido.Add(pedidoo);
            }
            int insertedRecords = db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);

        }
```

Modelo

```
public partial class Pedido
{
    public Pedido()
    {
        DetallePedido = new HashSet<DetallePedido>();
    }

    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    public string Producto { get; set; }
    public decimal? Precio { get; set; }
    public int? CantidadPedido { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DetallePedido> DetallePedido { get; set; }
}
```

Lo que he llegado a pensar y no estoy muy seguro es que en mi pagina cshtml no llamo el @modelo Pedido ya que estoy ocupando otro modelo para rellenar la tabla con los valores deseados, y no se si por no llamar el modelo Pedido me este dando error, pero no tengo idea.

Ejemplo de datos ingresados al array desde un console log 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El parámetro `List<Pedido> pedido` del controlador te está llegando a null?, o te llega con datos?

Comment: Creo que no me llega nada, hice un breakpoint y me muestra un Count = 0, pero no se como podria ver si realmente llegan los datos

Comment: Pero donde pusiste el break-point, en el `if`? o en el `foreach`.?. Pon el break-point en if y consulta si entra al if, para ver si viene a NULL.Por que si te das cuenta dentro del `if`creas una nueva instancia de `List<Pedido>()` y por eso puede darte `Count = 0`

Comment: Al pasar ecima de la palabra pedido del if me muestra el count = 0, y encima del null me muestra "null" pero soy nuevo en esto de los breakpoints y todo no se como funcionan muy bien, y con lo del if tambien ya probe quitandolo para ver si asi almacenaba algo y tampoco almacena nada.

Comment: Indica también en la pregunta los datos que tiene el  **array**, es importante para ver si se está haciendo bien la serialización a JSON.

Comment: He subido un ejemplo de los datos que almaceno en el array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lo he logrado haciendo estos cambios:

El JsonResult lo he cambiado por

```
public JsonResult InsertPedidos([FromBody]IEnumerable<Pedido> pedido)
        {       
            //Code...              
        }
```

Antes tenia

```
public JsonResult InsertPedidos(List<Pedido> pedido)
    {       
        //Code..
    }
```

La verdad no se cual sea la diferencia pero así me ha funcionado.

Comment: Una cosa... tu Controlador es un controlador de **Web API** ?

Comment: No hasta donde yo sepa, soy nuevo en esto de programar con ASP.Net @RafaelAcosta

Comment: En definitiva yo estoy utilizando el modelo MVC

Answer (score 0):

En principio tu pregunta tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema en la **serialización** del **Array** a **Json**.

Para que el Controlador pueda realizar el **Binding** de los datos que le llegan en **Json** al Modelo `Pedido`, estos deben mantener al menos **la misma estructura** en lo que se refiere a los **campos o propiedades** que cada uno de ellos tienen.

Si te fijas, en tu Modelo tienes el la propiedad `public int IdPedido { get; set; }`, la cual **no existe** en el Array.

Además también tienes en el Modelo la propiedad Virtual `public virtual ICollection<DetallePedido> DetallePedido { get; set; }` que tampoco existe en el **Array** que envías al servidor.

Prueba a incluir el campo `pedido.IdPedido` a la hora de **construir el Array** en la llamada Ajax, y si no te hace falta para grabar los pedidos en la BD, puedes quitar del Modelo la propiedad `public virtual ICollection<DetallePedido> DetallePedido { get; set; }` a ver si te funciona:

```
public partial class Pedido
{
public Pedido()
{
    // DetallePedido = new HashSet<DetallePedido>();
}

public int IdPedido { get; set; }
public string Producto { get; set; }
public decimal? Precio { get; set; }
public int? CantidadPedido { get; set; }
public string Estado { get; set; }

// public virtual ICollection<DetallePedido> DetallePedido { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Lo he logrado cambiando el tipo de parametro que le paso al JsonResult, lo cual lo describo en otra respuesta, y no le pasaba un parametro al "IdPedido" ya que lo he declarado como autoincrementable, lo demas de "DetallePedido" se refiere a la relacion de la tabla Pedido con esa tabla. Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Aca te dejo un ejemplo,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax

reviselo, talvez debas hacer un pequeño cambio, lo probe y funciona.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var things = [
        { id: 1, color: 'yellow' },
        { id: 2, color: 'blue' },
        { id: 3, color: 'red' }
    ];      

    things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/PassThings',
        data: things,
        success: function () {          
            $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    }); 
});


public void PassThings(List<Thing> things)
{
    var t = things;
}

public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Gracias a un ejemplo en ese link he logrado solucionarlo, la solucion la dejo abajo para que de repente le sirva a alguien mas, gracias.

Comment: GENIAL!!!! genial que haya funcionado

Comment: ahi lo arregle!